# MongoDB Return Inner Document From Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, projection

I am trying to fetch an element from an array in a document and only the element I don't want the entire document

I tried a different method but they all return the entire document

```
db.dept.find({"section.classes.CRN":"1901"}).limit(100)

db.dept.where("section.classes.CRN").eq("1901").limit(100)
json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d70ab0c280d6b8ebb850cc1"),
    "name" : "Art Studio",
    "abbr" : "ARS",
    "section" : [
        {
            "type" : "Undergraduate Courses",
            "classes" : [
                {
                    "CRN" : "193",
                    "Course" : "ARS100",
                    "Sec" : "01",
                    "Title" : "Drawing I",
                    "Cr" : "3",
                    "Dates" : "8/26-12/19",
                    "Days" : "MR",
                    "Time" : "1230P-0320P",
                    "Loc" : "SAB 226",
                    "Instructor" : "Schuck",
                    "Attributes" : "",
                    "Avail" : "F"
                },
                {
                    "CRN" : "293",
                    "Course" : "ARS100",
                    "Sec" : "02",
                    "Title" : "Drawing I",
                    "Cr" : "3",
                    "Dates" : "8/26-12/19",
                    "Days" : "MR",
                    "Time" : "0330P-0620P",
                    "Loc" : "SAB 226",
                    "Instructor" : "Itty",
                    "Attributes" : "",
                    "Avail" : "F"
                },
                {...
```

I am trying to get this or something similar when searching for a set of CRN values

```
json
 [  {
    "CRN" : "193",
    "Course" : "ARS100",
    "Sec" : "01",
    "Title" : "Drawing I",
    "Cr" : "3",
    "Dates" : "8/26-12/19",
    ...

    "Instructor" : "Schuck",
    "Attributes" : "",
    "Avail" : "F"
     }
   ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the aggregate pipeline to project double nested array as:

Input:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d70ab0c280d6b8ebb850cc1"),
    "name": "Art Studio",
    "abbr": "ARS",
    "section": [
      {
        "type": "Undergraduate Courses",
        "classes": [
          {
            "CRN": "193",
            "Course": "ARS100",
            "Sec": "01",
            "Title": "Drawing I",
            "Cr": "3",
            "Dates": "8/26-12/19",
            "Days": "MR",
            "Time": "1230P-0320P",
            "Loc": "SAB 226",
            "Instructor": "Schuck",
            "Attributes": "",
            "Avail": "F"
          },
          {
            "CRN": "293",
            "Course": "ARS100",
            "Sec": "02",
            "Title": "Drawing I",
            "Cr": "3",
            "Dates": "8/26-12/19",
            "Days": "MR",
            "Time": "0330P-0620P",
            "Loc": "SAB 226",
            "Instructor": "Itty",
            "Attributes": "",
            "Avail": "F"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Query:
hereafter unwinding section you can filter classes for CRN

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$section"
  },
  {
     $project: {
      name: 1,
      abbr: 1,
      "section.type": 1,
      "section.classes": {
       $filter: {
         input: "$section.classes",
         as: "item",
         cond: {
          $eq: [
            "$$item.CRN",
            "193"
          ]
        }
      }
  }
  }
},
 {
   $group: {
     _id: "$_id",
     section: {
       $push: "$section"
     }
   }
  }
])
```

Output:
you can manage your keys as you want in project for adding new keys or replacing them.

```
 [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d70ab0c280d6b8ebb850cc1"),
    "section": [
      {
        "classes": [
          {
            "Attributes": "",
            "Avail": "F",
            "CRN": "193",
            "Course": "ARS100",
            "Cr": "3",
            "Dates": "8/26-12/19",
            "Days": "MR",
            "Instructor": "Schuck",
            "Loc": "SAB 226",
            "Sec": "01",
            "Time": "1230P-0320P",
            "Title": "Drawing I"
          }
        ],
        "type": "Undergraduate Courses"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The pip works however I get other documents in the collection as well:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70bb69a1876ad9dd995882"), "section" :..
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d70bb69a1876ad9dd995884"), "section" :...

Comment: do you only want class array in response for one json or all jsons documents

Comment: Yes that works but I have multiple documents not just { "_id": ObjectId("5d70ab0c280d6b8ebb850cc1")}. I just need the one where a list of CRN occur

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1SBs1gdgPwH this will give an array of classes wherein all documents "CRN"= "193",

Comment: try above query it'll give you your required output

Comment: That works great! Is there a way to pass a list of CRN like ["193", "125"]

Answer (score 0):

```
db.dept.find({"section.classes.CRN":"1901"},{"section.classes":1}).limit(100)
```

It's called `projection` in mongodb, you pass a second object in find query to specify which fields you want in result.

so according to your above case if you want name, and section in result you should pass something like this

```
db.dept.find({"section.classes.CRN":"1901"},{"name":1, "section":1}).limit(100)
```

Comment: I have tried that, the query returns the entire document, I am only interested in getting back the single course like -> {"CRN": "193", "Course": "ARS100",..,} not that parent information.